# Eclipse and its portability from a linux to an other

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

at **work** I have a PC with Slackware 14 installed and **NO internet connection available**.
I need to install Eclipse with the latest android-sdk.

I tried to create an Eclipse & android-sdk tar.gz file from my home PC with Ubuntu installed.

On the work PC I've unpacked the tar.gz file, I've installed the lastest JRE, I've executed eclipse and, when asked, selected the android-sdk folder.

But, when I open an existing project (or create a new one), Eclipse shows me this error:

**R cannot be resolved to a variable eclipse**

The 'R' error is, for example, in the java source file in wich is called the name of the activity.

Eclipse suggest me to "**import Android.R**"...
If I make what eclipse suggests me the error moves to the activity name that follows 'R.id.' in the souce file!!!

Where is the mistake?
What have I forgot in the "transportation" phase?

Thanks

Comment: After importing the project, did you first build it ? You need to build the project first instead of doing a `Ctrl + Shift + O` .

Comment: @The Dark Knight: in the "Project" eclipse dropdown menu is selected "Build Automatically".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I don't know why and how, but the Ubuntu installation was corrupted!!!
Probably during the compression phase something gone wrong.
I've installed again and now I'm working at home and in my office!

Answer (score 1):

Hii i also got same problem with my Ubuntu PC I Think your Ubuntu Version is 64-bit one so you need to install some libraries before you continue for that you need  Internet Connection and after connecting type following command in teriminal

$sudo apt -get install ia32-libs

Comment: No, I have only 32 bit OS. Do I need some environment variables in order to work with eclipse/android-sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Android documentation says...

> Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask Eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them.

Press **Ctrl + Shift + O**

If it doesn't work, go to **Project tab -> Clean**

Tell us something ;)

Comment: This is true for existing projects, but I have this error also in NEW projects.

Comment: Well, did you checked your SDK's folder permissions?

Comment: Try cleaning your project or checking your sdk's folder permissions.

Comment: I've copied and extracted the tar file as root and I'm using eclipse as root

Comment: Now eclipse and android-sdk folders are readable and writeable by all, but the errors are the same. I've discovered another error (probably not seen before) in the "cinsole" tab: DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!